# Tooltip съезжают при скролле

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

У меня на странице элементы(tooltip) который при наведение должны отображать информацию, но почему-то они сьезжают [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно исправить?

```js
const QuestiontooltipRed = document.querySelector('.question-tooltip--red');
if(QuestiontooltipRed) {
  const productQuestion = document.querySelectorAll('.product__question--red');

  productQuestion.forEach(question => {
    question.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      QuestiontooltipRed.innerText = this.dataset.qustion;
      QuestiontooltipRed.style.top = e.y + 'px';
      QuestiontooltipRed.style.left = e.x  + 'px';
    })
  
    question.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      QuestiontooltipRed.style.display = 'block';
    })
  
    question.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      QuestiontooltipRed.style.display = 'none'
    })
  })
}
```

```css
.question-tooltip--red {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #a90000;
    width: 155px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 999;
    border: 2px solid #a90000;
}

.cart {
    &__wrapper {
        position: relative;
        padding: 47px 0 115px 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    &__items {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 25px;
        padding: 40px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(228, 228, 229, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0px 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 50px;
        max-width: 922px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
}

.cart-item {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E5;

    &__wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    &__content {
        padding: 0 15px;
        border-right: 1px solid #E4E4E5;;
        max-width: 422px;
    }

    &__heading {
        position: relative;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 29px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    &__title {
        width: 100%;
    }

    &__title-bc {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 60px;
        height: 27px;
        background: linear-gradient(270deg, #FFFFFF 18.75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    }


    &__checkbox {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    &__checkbox label {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    &__custom {
        margin-top: 25px;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 20px;
        max-width: 160px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: 1px;
    }

    &__desc {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 4px;
        margin: 12px 0 33px 0;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 15px;
        color: #323232;

        span {
            font-weight: 600;
        }
    }

    &__buttons {
        display: flex;
        gap: 5px;
    }

    &__price {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 25px;
        display: flex;
        gap: 1px;
    }

    &__details {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 220px;
    }

    &__img {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: #E4E4E5;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 22px;
        overflow: hidden;

        img {
            height: 200px;
        }
    }
}

.cart-item:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.cart-total {
    position: sticky;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 47px 0 115px 0;

    &__wrapper {
        box-shadow: 0px 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 50px;
        border: 2px solid #a90000;
        max-width: 350px;
    }

    &__body {
        padding: 40px 30px 30px 30px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 20px;
        width: 350px;
    }

    &__details {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E5;
    }

    &__quantity {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    &__price {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 29px;
    }

    &__info {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 22px;
        color: #6A6A6A;
    }

    &__sale {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    &__delivery {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    &__coupon-title {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    &__input {
        padding: 17px 15px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    &__coupon {
        position: relative;
    }

    .promo-active {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    &__enter {
        position: absolute;
        top: 24px;
        right: 0;
        padding: 15px 13px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        background: #fff;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    &__apply {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 0;
        border: 2px solid #a90000;
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-weight: 600;
        background: linear-gradient(88.01deg, #730000 -9.57%, #FF0000 115.37%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        background-clip: text;
        text-fill-color: transparent;
    }

    &__continue {
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        background: linear-gradient(88.01deg, #730000 -9.57%, #FF0000 115.37%);
        border-radius: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 0;
    }

    &__price-now {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="cart">
    <div class="container flex-container">
        <div class="cart__wrapper">
            <div class="cart__col">
                <div class="cart__items">
                    <div class="cart-item">
                    <div class="cart-item__wrapper">
                        <div class="cart-item__checkbox choose">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox8" checked>
                            <label for="checkbox8"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__img">
                            <img src="/images/cart/product.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__content">
                            <div class="cart-item__heading">
                                <h4 class="cart-item__title"><a href="/product.html" target="_blank">НАЗВАНИЕ ПРОДУКТА</a></h4>
                                <div class="cart-item__title-bc"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-item__desc">
                                <p class="cart-item__wish">
                                    <span>Ваши пожелания:</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                                    consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                </p>
                                <p class="cart-item__size"><span> Ориентировочные размеры:</span> 300*500*100 мм</p>
                                <p class="cart-item__options"><span>Дополнительные опции:</span> без опций</p>
                                <div class="cart-item__time"><span>Крайний срок готовности:</span> 09.08.2023</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-item__buttons">
                                <button><img src="/images/cart/delete.svg" alt="remove"></button>
                                <button class="cart-item__edit"><img src="/images/cart/edit.svg" alt="edit"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__details">
                        
                            <div class="counter">
                                <div class="counter__wrapper">
                                    <div class="counter__btn--minus" onclick="stepper(this)"><img src="/images/cart/minus.svg" class="disabled-minus disabled" alt="minus" draggable="false"></div>
                                    <input type="number" min="1" max="9999" step="1" value="1" class="counter__input">
                                    <div class="counter__btn--plus" onclick="stepper(this)"><img src="/images/cart/plus.svg" alt="plus" draggable="false"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            

                            <div class="price">
                                <div class="price__now cart-item__price">
                                    <p>от 417.00 BYN</p> 
                                    <div class="product__question--red" data-qustion="Краткая подсказка: например, по цене: ещё раз повторить, что она не окончательная">
                                      <img src="/images/icons/red-qustion.svg" alt="question">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                <div class="price__sale">
                                  <p class="price__cost">от 507.00 BYN</p>
                                  <p class="price__percent">-18%</p>
                                  <div class="product__time" data-qustion="До конца акции 5 дней, 5 часов и 5 минут!">
                                    <img src="/images/cart/sale.svg" alt="sale">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-item">
                    <div class="cart-item__wrapper">
                        <div class="cart-item__checkbox choose">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox9" checked>
                            <label for="checkbox9"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__img">
                            <img src="/images/cart/product.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__content">
                            <div class="cart-item__heading">
                                <h4 class="cart-item__title"><a href="/product.html" target="_blank">НАЗВАНИЕ ПРОДУКТА</a></h4>
                                <div class="cart-item__title-bc"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-item__desc">
                                <p class="cart-item__wish">
                                    <span>Ваши пожелания:</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                                    consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                </p>
                                <p class="cart-item__size"><span> Ориентировочные размеры:</span> 300*500*100 мм</p>
                                <p class="cart-item__options"><span>Дополнительные опции:</span> без опций</p>
                                <div class="cart-item__time"><span>Крайний срок готовности:</span> 09.08.2023</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-item__buttons">
                                <button><img src="/images/cart/delete.svg" alt="remove"></button>
                                <button class="cart-item__edit"><img src="/images/cart/edit.svg" alt="edit"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__details">
                            <div class="counter">
                                <div class="counter__wrapper">
                                    <div class="counter__btn--minus" onclick="stepper(this)"><img src="/images/cart/minus.svg" class="disabled-minus disabled" alt="minus" draggable="false"></div>
                                    <input type="number" min="1" max="9999" step="1" value="1" class="counter__input">
                                    <div class="counter__btn--plus" onclick="stepper(this)"><img src="/images/cart/plus.svg" alt="plus" draggable="false"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">
                                <div class="price__now cart-item__price">
                                    <p>от 417.00 BYN</p> 
                                    <div class="product__question--red" data-qustion="Краткая подсказка: например, по цене: ещё раз повторить, что она не окончательная">
                                      <img src="/images/icons/red-qustion.svg" alt="question">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                <div class="price__sale">
                                  <p class="price__cost">от 507.00 BYN</p>
                                  <p class="price__percent">-18%</p>
                                  <div class="product__time" data-qustion="До конца акции 5 дней, 5 часов и 5 минут!">
                                    <img src="/images/cart/sale.svg" alt="sale">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-item">
                    <div class="cart-item__wrapper">
                        <div class="cart-item__checkbox choose">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox10" checked>
                            <label for="checkbox10"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__img">
                            <img src="/images/cart/product.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__content">
                            <div class="cart-item__heading">
                                <h4 class="cart-item__title"><a href="/product.html" target="_blank">НАЗВАНИЕ ПРОДУКТА</a></h4>
                                <div class="cart-item__title-bc"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-item__desc">
                                <p class="cart-item__wish">
                                    <span>Ваши пожелания:</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                                    consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                </p>
                                <p class="cart-item__size"><span> Ориентировочные размеры:</span> 300*500*100 мм</p>
                                <p class="cart-item__options"><span>Дополнительные опции:</span> без опций</p>
                                <div class="cart-item__time"><span>Крайний срок готовности:</span> 09.08.2023</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-item__buttons">
                                <button><img src="/images/cart/delete.svg" alt="remove"></button>
                                <button class="cart-item__edit"><img src="/images/cart/edit.svg" alt="edit"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__details">
                            <div class="counter">
                                <div class="counter__wrapper">
                                    <div class="counter__btn--minus" onclick="stepper(this)"><img src="/images/cart/minus.svg" class="disabled-minus disabled" alt="minus" draggable="false"></div>
                                    <input type="number" min="1" max="9999" step="1" value="1" class="counter__input">
                                    <div class="counter__btn--plus" onclick="stepper(this)"><img src="/images/cart/plus.svg" alt="plus" draggable="false"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">
                                <div class="price__now cart-item__price">
                                    <p>от 417.00 BYN</p> 
                                    <div class="product__question--red" data-qustion="Краткая подсказка: например, по цене: ещё раз повторить, что она не окончательная">
                                      <img src="/images/icons/red-qustion.svg" alt="question">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-item">
                    <div class="cart-item__wrapper">
                        <div class="cart-item__checkbox choose">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox11" checked>
                            <label for="checkbox11"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__img">
                            <img src="/images/all-product/poker.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__content">
                            <div class="cart-item__heading">
                                <h4 class="cart-item__title"><a href="/product.html" target="_blank">НАГРАДЫ ПО ВАШЕМУ ДИЗАЙНУ</a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-item__desc">
                                <p class="cart-item__wish">
                                    <span>Ваши пожелания:</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                                    consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                </p>
                                <p class="cart-item__size"><span> Ориентировочные размеры:</span> 300*500*100 мм</p>
                                <p class="cart-item__options"><span>Дополнительные опции:</span> без опций</p>
                                <div class="cart-item__time"><span>Крайний срок готовности:</span> 09.08.2023</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-item__buttons">
                                <button><img src="/images/cart/delete.svg" alt="remove"></button>
                                <button class="cart-item__edit"><img src="/images/cart/edit.svg" alt="edit"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item__details">
                            <div class="counter">
                                <div class="counter__wrapper">
                                    <div class="counter__btn--minus" onclick="stepper(this)"><img src="/images/cart/minus.svg" class="disabled-minus disabled" alt="minus" draggable="false"></div>
                                    <input type="number" min="1" max="9999" step="1" value="1" class="counter__input">
                                    <div class="counter__btn--plus" onclick="stepper(this)"><img src="/images/cart/plus.svg" alt="plus" draggable="false"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-item__custom">
                                <p>Просчитывается 
                                <div class="product__question--red" data-qustion="Краткая подсказка: например, по цене: ещё раз повторить, что она не окончательная">
                                    <img src="/images/icons/red-qustion.svg" alt="question">
                                </div>
                                индивидуально</p> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="info" id="info">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="info__wrapper cart-info__wrapper">
                        <div class="info__body">
                            <div class="info__item">
                                <div class="info__title">ЦЕНЫ И СРОКИ</div>
                                <div class="info__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info__item">
                                <div class="info__title">ОПЛАТА И ДОСТАВКА</div>
                                <div class="info__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info__item">
                                <div class="info__title">КОНТАКТЫ</div>
                                <div class="info__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info__item">
                                <div class="info__title">О НАС</div>
                                <div class="info__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <aside class="cart-total">
                <div class="cart-total__wrapper">
                    <div class="cart-total__body">
                        <h4 class="cart-total__title title">ИТОГО</h4>
                        <div class="cart-total__details">
                            <div class="cart-total__quantity">2 товара на сумму</div>
                            <div class="cart-total__price-now">
                                <div class="cart-total__price">от 556.00 BYN</div> 
                                <div class="product__question--red" data-qustion="Краткая подсказка: например, по цене: ещё раз повторить, что она не окончательная">
                                  <img src="/images/icons/red-qustion.svg" alt="question">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-total__info">
                            <div class="cart-total__sale">
                                <p>Сумма скидок</p>
                                <p class="red-text">-120.00 BYN</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-total__delivery">
                                <p>Доставка</p>
                                <p class="red-text">Бесплатно</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-total__coupon">
                            <h6 class="cart-total__coupon-title">Скидочный купон</h6>
                            <input type="text" class="cart-total__input input-text" placeholder="Введите здесь">
                            <button class="cart-total__enter"><img src="/images/cart/enter-promo.svg" alt=""></button>
                        </div>
                        <button class="cart-total__continue">Продолжить</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="question-tooltip--red"></div>
     <div class="tooltip--time"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [mcve] не хотите привести?